# Hazelcast map max-size configuration without eviction policy

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap, hazelcast-jet

In hazelcast Map configuration,if we set  eviction-policy to None and Used max-idle-seconds,time-to-live-seconds like below ,

```
<map name="simpleMap">
<backup-count>0</backup-count>
<max-idle-seconds>360</max-idle-seconds> <time-to-live-seconds>30</time-to-live-seconds>
<eviction-policy>NONE</eviction-policy>
<max-size>3000</max-size>
<eviction-percentage>30</eviction-percentage>
<merge-policy>com.hazelcast.map.merge.PutIfAbsentMapMergePolicy</merge-policy>
```

Can someone explain,In this case max-size will work or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuring `max-size` with no eviction policy is not a valid configuration. Please check the description [here](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/3.12.z/hazelcast/src/main/resources/hazelcast-full-example.xml#L969).

> If you want max-size to work, set the  to a value other than NONE.